# Evaluating SKI-combinators with not enough arguments

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinators, combinatory-logic, k-combinator, s-combinator

I was tasked with showing that

**S(KK)I = K**

Now since **S** takes **three** arguments, I was simply stuck at the beginning not knowing how to tackle this. I see two arguments, namely **(KK)** and **I** but there is no third one I can "spot". What happens in this situation? It sort of worked for me already by just leaving out the **z** in **S x y z = xz(yz)**, which yielded **KK(I)** and as a consequence **K**. It just seems wrong to me though so I want to ask here. Is this the right way of going about it?

I also dont understand what happens with **KI** for example as **K** also needs two arguments and only gets **I**. Is my solution right or do I have to go about it differently?

Comment: Hint: S(KK)I = K means the left side applied to any combinator x equals the right side applied to the same combinator x.

Comment: I believe you're wrong when you say I only see two arguments (KK). KK is in fact the first  argument of S. I is the second. We're missing a third. As explained below, just add a third argument z, to S(KK)I and simplify it. You'll see it's KZ. Similarly you can sww that SK =KI

Answer (score 1):

The way I think of this is that **S(KK)I** is a function that takes a single argument - call it `z`. What happens when we invoke this function with an arbitrary `z`?

```
S(KK)Iz -> KKz(Iz) -> Kz
```

So invoking **S(KK)I** with `z` is exactly the same as invoking **K** with `z`. Therefore, **S(KK)I** and **K** are the same function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve your question is the use of eta-conversion.
Namely, every term M behaves like a term (λx.M x) (of course, x cannot be free in M). Thus, if the combinators you want to evaluate lack some arguments, you can eta-convert the term and then apply these combinators.

Given your example, you need two eta-conversions. The reductions after the first one are given below.

```
S(KK)I -> λx.S(KK)Ix -> λx.KKx(Ix) -> λx.K(Ix)
```

Now you have the outer combinator K that lacks the second argument. If you eta-convert the outermost term: λy.(λx.**K**(**I**x)) y, you will get λy.**K**(**I**y), which is not very amusing. But you can apply eta-conversion to a subterm of the term, e.g. a body of lambda abstraction. Thus, you can convert λx.**K**(**I**x) to λx.(λy.**K**(**I**x) y). That results in λx.λy.**I**x, which reduces to λx.λy.x, and this term is a definition of **K** combinator. Voila!

In fact, you can prove equivalence of combinators without using eta-conversion, but then you need to use some not-very-friendly axioms as rewriting rules (for details, see Chapter 7 of Henk P. Barendregt (1984). The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics).

Answer (score 0):

This is, in effect, what [Combo](https://github.com/RockBrentwood/Combo) (which I put up on GitHub) does when it's run with extensionality turned on:

```
    S (K K) I
    = λx·S (K K) I x        ⇒       λx·K K x (I x)  ⇒       λx·K (I x)      
    = λx·λy·K (I x) y       ⇒       λx·λy·I x       ⇒       λx·λy·x
    = λx·K x
    = K
```

The steps it actually shows are:

```
    S (K K) I #0 => K K #0 (I #0)
    K K #0 => K
    K (I #0) #1 => I #0
    I #0 => #0
    K
```